# Convergence of MacLaurin series of function $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x^3)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I need to prove the convergence of this MacLaurin series by using the fact that $|f^{(n)} (x)| \leq kM^n \;\;\;\;\forall x \in (-r,r)$.

I found the MacLaurin series and I found the radius of convergence but how do I find the $n$-th derivative and also how do I find $k$ and $M.$

I have also other examples that I need to solve using this convergence criteria so it would be very nice if somebody would help me out and explain the idea how I can solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "by using the fact that...". Is this fact given to you or you have to estbalish such an estimate and proceed from there? Once you have an estimate like that you can use the Taylor formula with Lagrange remainder to prove the convergence of your power series.

Comment: It was given to me as a theorem. Could you please walk me through it?

Comment: Could you please quote the whole exercise exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* true that $|f^{(n)}(x)|<kM^n$ for all $x$ in $(-r,r)$.

In fact, the Maclaurin series is $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{3n+1}$. It is obvious that this series converges for $|x|<1$.

Using the formula $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$, you can see that $f^{(3n+1)}(0)=(-1)^n(3n+1)!$.

$(3n+1)!$ grows faster than $kM^{3n+1}$ for any $k,M$.

Comment: So how do I prove that for |x|<1 it actually converges toward the function?

Comment: $\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{3n+1}\right|\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x|^n$. To prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x|^n$ converges, use the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{k} |x|^n=\frac{1-|x|^k}{1-x}$.